# Scipy's bfgs for CEC2013 benchmark functions with 30 dimensions -> precision loss for Rotated Bent Cigar & Rotated Schaffers F7

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, loss-function, dimensions

I'm using Scipy's BFGS on built CEC2013 benchmark functions(source: https://github.com/Naeemeh146/cec-benchmark-2013-python), but the function of Rotated Bent Cigar and the function of Rotated Schaffers F7 didn't work well under 30 dimensions. Both of the functions got precision loss. I'm new to the optimization and I've googled a lot but I still don't know how to solve this...

**Reproduce the problem of Rotated Bent Cigar**
After importing the bfgs from scipy, I used np.ones(30) as the initial point (x0). For Rotated Bent Cigar, I set gtol=1e-9 so that the result value won't be "nan".
    `from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs fmin_bfgs(f3, np.ones(30), fprime=None, args=(), gtol=1e-9, norm=float('inf'), epsilon=math.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps), maxiter=None, full_output=0, disp=1, retall=0, callback=None)`

**Output I got**
`    RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
Y = Z[0]**2 + 1e6 * np.sum(Z[1:]**2) - 1200

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
Y = Z[0]**2 + 1e6 * np.sum(Z[1:]**2) - 1200

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract 
df = fun(x) - f0

Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
     Current function value: 77457993654581510275072.000000
     Iterations: 28
     Function evaluations: 3524
     Gradient evaluations: 113`
```

**Reproduce the problem of Rotated Schaffers F7**
For Rotated Schaffers F7, I used the default value of gtol=1e-5 as below:
    `fmin_bfgs(f7, np.ones(30), fprime=None, args=(), gtol=1e-5, norm=float('inf'), epsilon=math.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps), maxiter=None, full_output=0, disp=1, retall=0, callback=None)`

**Output I got**
    `Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss. Current function value: 2406912647990380032.000000 Iterations: 1 Function evaluations: 1531 Gradient evaluations: 49`

**The benchmark functions code**
The benchmark function code were written as below, using this [code](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).
`.      def read_M(self , dim , m):
return self.rotate_data[m * dim : (m + 1) * dim]

```
    def shift_data(self , dim , m):
        return np.array(self.sd[m * dim : (m + 1) * dim])

    def carat(self , dim , alpha):    # I don't know this is correct or not!!!
        return alpha ** (np.arange(dim)/(2*(dim-1)))

    def T_asy(self , X , Y, beta):
        D = len(X)
        for i in range(D):
            if X[i] > 0:
                Y[i] = X[i] ** (1 + beta * (i/(D-1)) * np.sqrt(X[i])  ) 
        pass


    # Rotated Bent Cigar Function
    # 3
    def f3(self,X):
        X_shift = X - self.O
        X_rotate = self.M1 @ X_shift
        self.T_asy(X_rotate ,X_shift, 0.5)
        Z = self.M2 @ X_shift

        Y = Z[0]**2 + 1e6 * np.sum(Z[1:]**2) - 1200
        return Y

    # Rotated Schaffers F7 Function
    # 7
    def f7(self,X):
        d = len(X)
        X_shift = X - self.O
        X_rotate = self.M1 @ X_shift
        self.T_asy(X_rotate , X_shift, 0.5)
        Z = self.M2 @ (self.carat(d , 10) * X_shift)

        Z = np.sqrt(Z[:-1]**2 + Z[1:]**2)
        Y = (np.sum(np.sqrt(Z) + np.sqrt(Z) * np.sin(50 * Z**0.2)**2 ) / (d-1))**2 - 800
        return Y
```

`

Note: I really appriciate any help I get from you. Wish you the best.‍♀️

I tried to change the value of epsilon to make it smaller but it didn't help either.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example